# Will Sitecore support Jpeg 2000 , Jpeg XR, webp image format by default?

Tags: media-library

We have recommendation from our seo team to use image format like jpeg 2000, jpeg XR, webp but when we try to upload Jpeg 2000 image with extension .jp2, sitecore not taking as image format instead it takes as file.
Are we missing any configuration to support these image format?

Comment: Hi Kanmani, welcome to SSE! Unless there is a high demand, Sitecore is unlikely to add this by default. Richard did however provide with a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

welcome to SSE.

For Sitecore to recognize a `.jp2` extension, you would need to set that up in the configuration of the media types.

Out of the box, the `jpeg` configuration is like this:

```
<mediaType name="JPEG image" extensions="jpg, jpeg, jpe, jfif">
    <mimeType>image/jpeg</mimeType>
    <forceDownload>false</forceDownload>
    <sharedTemplate>system/media/unversioned/jpeg</sharedTemplate>
    <versionedTemplate>system/media/versioned/jpeg</versionedTemplate>
    <mediaValidator type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.ImageValidator"/>
    <thumbnails>
        <generator type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.ImageThumbnailGenerator, Sitecore.Kernel">
            <extension>png</extension>
        </generator>
        <width>150</width>
        <height>150</height>
        <backgroundColor>#FFFFFF</backgroundColor>
    </thumbnails>
    <prototypes>
        <media type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.JpegMedia, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    </prototypes>
</mediaType>
```

Notice that in the `extentions` attribute, `jp2` is missing. You could either patch that to add `jp2` or just add a new mediaType with the `jp2` extension like this:

```
<mediaType name="JPEG image" extensions="jp2">
    <mimeType>image/jpeg</mimeType>
    <forceDownload>false</forceDownload>
    <sharedTemplate>system/media/unversioned/jpeg</sharedTemplate>
    <versionedTemplate>system/media/versioned/jpeg</versionedTemplate>
    <mediaValidator type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.ImageValidator"/>
    <thumbnails>
        <generator type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.ImageThumbnailGenerator, Sitecore.Kernel">
            <extension>png</extension>
        </generator>
        <width>150</width>
        <height>150</height>
        <backgroundColor>#FFFFFF</backgroundColor>
    </thumbnails>
    <prototypes>
        <media type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.JpegMedia, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    </prototypes>
</mediaType>
```

Depending on your IIS settings you may also need to add a mime type in your web.config like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".jp2" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".jp2" mimeType="image/jp2"/>
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Its virtually the same solution for svg files from this post: [Inserting SVG files/markup](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11085/inserting-svg-files-markup)

Comment: Will Sitecore's image resizing handler support these new formats out of the box?

Comment: @mp1990 if you have further questions, please open these as a new question