# Sitecore 7.2 and Jpeg2000 image types

Tags: media-library, patch-configuration

Is it possible to configure the Sitecore media library to recognize `jpeg2000` files such as `.jp2`? I've tried using [this solution](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/14145/3907). However, when uploading `jp2` types to the media library it throws an error saying

```
The file does not exist or the path is wrong
```

Comment: Asking the same question twice is not what we do here. Post enough information about the way you have implemented it, and specifically where your implementation differs from the already given answer.

Comment: @MarkCassidy I've implemented it exactly the same as in the answer, I was thinking this may be because I'm working with an old version of Sitecore - hence the 7.2 reference in the title.