# How do you render an svg element with the SXA rendering variants?

Tags: sxa

I need to render a image in SVG format on my site. I want to create another rendering variant of the SXA Image Rendering Variant, so that the image is rendered as SVG.
With the current Image Rendering Variant renders image as

```
<a title="LW Logo Image Link" href="/"><img src="/-/media/Project/LW/LW/logo-lmage.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=F9D590BA05C61D36E9D5808F830D3D29" alt="" data-variantitemid="{F10CA728-FEDA-4706-B8D6-1651842E4BBA}" data-variantfieldname="Image"></a>
```

I want the new variant to render the image as

```
<svg role="img" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"width="500"height="40" viewBox="0 0 500 40" overflow="visible"><path d="M489 26.8v-5.5h2.2c3........."></path></g></svg>
```

Can this be done with creating a new Rendering variant or do I need to create a custom SXA component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want control over the markup using C# then you can try something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <renderField>
        <processor
          patch:instead="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetImageFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel']"
          type="Company.Foundation.Media.Pipelines.RenderField.GetImageFieldValue, Scms.Foundation.Media" />
      </renderField>
    </pipelines>
   </sitecore>
 </configuration>
```

```csharp
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField;

namespace Company.Foundation.Media.Pipelines.RenderField
{
    public class GetImageFieldValue : Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetImageFieldValue
    {
        public override void Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)args, nameof(args));
            if (!this.IsImage(args))
            {
                return;
            }

            var renderer = new ImageRendererEx();
            this.ConfigureRenderer(args, renderer);
            this.SetRenderFieldResult(renderer.Render(), args);
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Data.Fields;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Xml.Xsl;

namespace Company.Foundation.Media.Pipelines.RenderField
{
    public class ImageRendererEx : ImageRenderer
    {
        public override RenderFieldResult Render()
        {
            var obj = Item;
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return RenderFieldResult.Empty;
            }

            var attributes = Parameters;

            if (attributes == null)
            {
                return RenderFieldResult.Empty;
            }

            var width = MainUtil.GetInt(Extract(attributes, "width", "w"), 0);
            var height = MainUtil.GetInt(Extract(attributes, "height", "h"), 0);
            var scale = MainUtil.GetFloat(Extract(attributes, "scale", "sc"), 0.0f);
            var maxWidth = MainUtil.GetInt(Extract(attributes, "maxWidth", "mw"), 0);
            var maxHeight = MainUtil.GetInt(Extract(attributes, "maxHeight", "mh"), 0);

            var innerField = obj.Fields[FieldName];

            if (innerField == null) return base.Render();

            var imageField = new ImageField(innerField, FieldValue);

            ParseField(imageField);
            AdjustImageSize(imageField, scale, maxWidth, maxHeight, ref width, ref height);

            if (imageField.MediaItem == null) return base.Render();

            var imageMediaItem = new MediaItem(imageField.MediaItem);

            if (imageMediaItem.MimeType == "image/svg+xml")
            {
                return new RenderFieldResult(RenderSvgImage(imageMediaItem, width, height));
            }

            return base.Render();
        }

        private string RenderSvgImage(MediaItem mediaItem, int width, int height)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(mediaItem, nameof(mediaItem));

            string result;

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(mediaItem.GetMediaStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            var svg = XDocument.Parse(result);

            if (svg.Document?.Root == null) return result;

            if (width > 0)
            {
                svg.Document.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", width);
            }

            if (height > 0)
            {
                svg.Document.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", height);
            }

            result = svg.ToString();

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**Comments:** If you really want to be fancy you can use similar code but turn it into a Scriban function.

Comment: When we add same .svg file (animated ) then animation does not work for second one through this code.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new rendering variant and add a Scriban template under it.
[image]

This worked for me just fine

[image]

Make sure to select your new rendering variant on the rendering itself:
[image]

[image]

Edit:
If you store the inline SVGs in, say a multi line text field on the item the scriban template can call them with `{{i_page.SvgField}}`

More on SVG syntax can be found here and in the 3 child articles:
[Scriban templates](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/scriban-templates.html)

If you want to properly integrate SVGs into Sitecore you have to follow one of the blog posts:
[Inserting SVG files/markup](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11085/inserting-svg-files-markup)

[Adding an SVG image to the Media Library](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/1670)

Once you have the C# code to get a Media Library item's SVG value you can integrate with scriban, to do something like `{{my_custom_function i_item "ImageFieldWithSvg"}}`

[Creating Custom Embedded Function in Scriban](https://blogs.perficient.com/2020/08/03/sxa-scriban-creating-custom-embedded-function-in-scriban/)

Comment: How exactly does this render the actual image selected in the field? This is just hard coding an SVG into the template