# SVG file showing as plain image in image component

Tags: sxa

I am using `Sitecore 9.1` with `SXA 1.8`. I have uploaded `SVG` file under media library. It is showing perfectly there but when I am trying to get it on the image component then it is showing as a plain image.

Comment: are you using scriban component to render svg image?

Comment: No @praveensoni

Answer (score 1):

The classic SXA renderings will render an image with the help of the `<img />` tag. Even if you choose an `SVG` file it will still be rendered as `<img />` with `src` attribute referencing to your `SVG` file, not as `<svg />` tag.

If you would like to have the full control over your HTML markup you will need to create a new rendering. More technical details about HOW with EXAMPLES you can find in a similar discussion [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/28431/how-do-you-render-an-svg-element-with-the-sxa-rendering-variants).